# How to define this situation in English?

Tags: spoken-english

Actually I don't have words to explain my matter but I'll try to make myself understood. If I want to order somebody to put/remove/take some thing out of desk or from cupboard how should I say. Is it correct way to say so:

> Pick X-object out of desk of cupboard
>
> Bring that object down from cupboard's top

Answer (score 3):

You could say "Get that X-object out of the desk for me"
And you could also say "Bring that object that's in the cupboard to me"

Hope this helps, English can be confusing to learn.

Comment: And If that object is on top of cupboard, then what should I say? I mean it's lying on the upper surface of that cupboard

Comment: For that you could say, "Get that object that's on top of the cupboard down and bring it to me".